# Autosave *scratch* to a directory

Tags: emacs24.4, auto-save, scratch-buffer

When typing `ls` in my home directory, I amm greeted by a lot of this:

```
#%2Ascratch%2A#1399_po# #%2Ascratch%2A#14484YsZ# [...]
```

I also have the following in my `init.el`

```el
(defvar autosave-location (concat user-emacs-directory "data/autosave"))

(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
  `((".*" ,autosave-location t)))
```

Why, then are the scratch autosaves not being sent to `~/.emacs.d/data/autosave` and instead are being blasted around my file system? Ideally, I just want it to save to that folder, however if that can't be done, disabling autosave for `*scratch*` buffers entirely would suffice.

I believe this started with Emacs 24.4.

Comment: In your setup, is the `*scratch*` a file-visiting-buffer or a NON-file-visiting buffer?  The default is the latter and thus is not subject to autosave.  I like to kill the `*scratch*` when Emacs opens and prevent it from reappearing, and instead I use a custom file-visiting-buffer called `.scratch`.  Whenever `*scratch*` would normally appear, I preempt it with a custom `find-file /path/to/.scratch`

Comment: It is _not_ a file-visiting buffer (and I would rather it stay that way), which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Emacs does not, by default, autosave NON-file-visiting buffers.  For example, a `*Help*` buffer does not get autosaved, nor does a `*Backtrace*` buffer.

Comment: Apparently, it will if you enable `auto-save-mode` in the buffer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849661/is-it-possible-to-autosave-temporary-buffers-that-are-not-visiting-a-file

Comment: @lawlist I would like to do something similar to what you describe with `.scratch`.  Are you able to provide details?  It would be a huge help

Comment: @JonahHuron -- Please feel free to write up a new question once you have conducted a preliminary search to ascertain whether a similar/same quesition/answer already exists.  If you find similar questions/answers that do not answer your question, then perhaps mention those links in your new question and state why those other questions/answers are insufficient for your particular use-case; i.e., distinguish them so that your new question is not erroneously closed as being duplicative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll notice that you're using a variable called `auto-save-file-name-transforms`. Since `*scratch*` has no filename, it falls back to autosaving in `default-directory`.

For the `*scratch*` buffer, or any other buffers like this with no filename,  you can use:

```
(setq-local default-directory "~/.emacs.d/data/autosave")
```

Edit: I see that you don't really care about autosaving scratch buffers. Can I ask how you enable `auto-save-mode` in your init? You should use:

```
 (setq-default auto-save-default t)
```

And not something like a hook with `(auto-save-mode 1)`, because the variable only enables it for file-visiting buffers, while a hook could potentially enable it for buffers where you don't want it.

Comment: Yes and yes. I suppose I'll just disable it entirely for `*scratch*` then.