# Can I recover the contents of a scratch buffer?

Tags: scratch-buffer, recover

Using Ubuntu 22.04.  I accidentally closed a scratch buffer that I had notes in.  Can I recover those contents?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  (1) About `*scratch*`? or *buffer*?  (2) scratch message? or *buffer* content?  If both the latter one, why did you mention `*scratch*` here?

Comment: Was the buffer a scratch buffer (as in: you scribbled in it but neglected to save it),or the `*scratch*` buffer (as in: the buffer that Emacs normally provides automatically, so you can evaluate Lisp expressions in it)? Was the buffer you closed associated with a file? If so, there may be some hope. If not ...

Comment: If not, did you `lossage-size` a large number? If so, there may be some hope. If not ...

Comment: @shynur I'm not sure what you're asking.  I'm not familiar with your vocabulary, I guess.  When I open a new Emacs GUI instance from the OS menu, it opens as a new window that says *scratch* at the bottom.  That's what I lost.

Comment: Those all are legit questions. If that's a `*scratch*` buffer created by default by Emacs, [Ask for saving contents if scratch buffer is modified before exit](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36563/28451) may help you next time. See also [Autosave *scratch* to a directory](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7729/28451) thread.